# On parse-server, is there an alternative way to query as a user, without a 'Session' object?

Tags: session, parse-platform, acl, parse-server

Our API is built on parse (parseplatform.org).

I have a background job which needs to run queries on behalf of users; it needs to ensure that the queries only find/update objects that the user's ACL allows.

For most users, I can query the `Parse.Session` class to get the `sessionToken` for the given user, and then use that on all requests, e.g. `query.find({sessionToken: "r:xxx"})`.

But for some users, the only `session` object available have expired, and for many, there are no `session` objects at all.

As far as I'm aware, creating `Parse.Session` instances is not possible; the only way to generate a session is by calling `Parse.User.logIn`; but this is not an option for us, mainly because we would need the user's password (which we do not have), but also because it results in memory leaks on `parse-server` environments.

Has anyone come across a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

For background jobs where there is no user you should use the following

query.find({useMasterKey: true});

useMasterKey will bypass any ACL security restrictions. Perfect for Batch jobs.

Just be careful that anything else that calls this code will also use the masterKey. Sometimes I will add the following code before to ensure that the correct access is used

```
var findOptions={};
if (request.user){
  findOptions = {sessionToken:request.user.getSessionToken()};
} else {
  findOptions = {useMasterKey:true};
}

query.find(findOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks Alon, but I don't want to use the mastery key as that will return objects that the user is not supposed to see - I need to only find objects that fall within the user's read rights so that when I eventually send the objects to them - they can load it on their account.

Comment: Try using the 'become' method. Not sure if you have the sessionToken stored somewhere but if you do you can use that http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_become

Comment: Its the fact that we don't have sessionTokens stored for some users that's causing this issue; also the `become` method is not safe in cloud code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why become is not safe in cloud code?

Comment: If I remember correctly, that function will set a user object on Parse.User.current, which is globally accessible. In a server environment, that will result in state/memory leaking.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this.

Comment: Thanks Alon! Let me know if you come across any solutions

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might just need to run the code *when* they log in (and therefore you have a session token).

You could also try running the code with the master keys but that comes with its own problems.

Comment: I'm trying to do some things in the background for them (organizing / accessing their content) so that we can email them when new things are ready?

I could use the master keys but then it will give me access to information that they don't have access to so I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it?

If there's no other way i'll give it a try with running the code when they log in rather than doing it as a batch background job